# Method that can accept various types

Tags: c#

I wanted to know if there was a way to create a method that can accept variable data types.
Sometime I need to pass objects to that method sometimes primitive types such as

```
SomeMethod(object);
SomeMEthod(r,p,q); //Where r,p,q are integers
```

What would the signature of such a method look like ?

Comment: How are these parameters used?

Comment: What do you plan to do with that data?  That's what *really* drives the answer.  Remember pretty much everything is an `object`, so that could be enough, depending on what you actually do with it.

Comment: Agree with the above comment by Servy, there are multiple options to achieve what you want (params variable, overloading, generic methods), but which one to choose depends on what is going to happen for the different types you may pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the type before hand, and it can really be ANY type, then an `object` parameter would work for both, reference and value types.

Example:

```
public static void Method(params object[] list) 
{
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.Length ; i++ )
      Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
}

Method(1, 'a', "test");
```

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about the type of parameters in the method, you could simply use:

```
public void SomeMethod(params object[] list)
```

If you need to treat types of parameters differently, you'll have to be more specific and create several overloads of the method that are strongly typed.

Comment: Could also declare `public void SomeMethod<T>(params T[] list)` to avoid boxing (but would be locked to a specific type)

Answer (score 1):

There's also method overloading  where you pass multiple methods with the same name but different signatures.

```
public void SomeMethod(object o)
{
}

public void SomeMethod(int r, int p, int q)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method to accept any number of any type, even if can be very slow and unmaintainable:

```
void Foo(params object[] arguments)
{
    //Operate
}
```

The above method will work for almost any type, but in case of value types it will have to box them, which requires processing. If you want to make your code a bit more performant, I suggest you to create overloads to fit your needs.